# Using ffmpeg in node, without using fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, child-process

I am using ffmpeg without using fluent-ffmpeg. I am using 'child_process' from node.

First of all I verified how can I pass more than one arguments to the child process command. and I verified it given below code.

I used copy command like this

> cp vid1.mp4 vid2.mp4

which successfully copied vid1 into vid2.

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const child = execFile('cp', ['vid1.mp4', 'vid3.mp4'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('stderr: =============================', stderr);
        throw error;
    }
    console.log('stdout: ==========================', stdout);
});

console.log('here');
```

Above code is content of the 'index.js'(default entry point in node). And running this with **node .** , which copies vid1 into vid3 successfully.

Now, I want to do watermarking to the given video. For that I am using this [tutorial](http://ksloan.net/watermarking-videos-from-the-command-line-using-ffmpeg-filters/). Currently link to the actual tutorial is broken, you can see it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171014223740/http://ksloan.net/watermarking-videos-from-the-command-line-using-ffmpeg-filters/).

This is the command that I am using

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" output.mp4
```

Now the same command I am using like this ,

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

const child = execFile('ffmpeg', ['-i', 'input.mp4' , '-i' , 'logo.png' , '-filter_complex' , '"overlay=10:10"' , 'output.mp4' ], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('stderr: =============================', stderr);
        throw error;
    }
    console.log('stdout: ==========================', stdout);
});

console.log('here');
```

and I am getting an error , that ,

> No such filter: '"overlay' Error initializing complex filters. Invalid
>   argument
>
> /Users/neerpatel/Desktop/testProjects/childProcess/index.js:7
>           throw error;
>           ^
>
> Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png
>   -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" output.mp4

You can clearly see that the same command that runs in terminal directly, doesn't work when I pass it in child process. Why does it happen ?

Moreover, I wanted to add tag 'watermarking' , but I can't create tag since my reputation is below 1500. please, someone do it.

UPDATE : 
I used EXEC , instead of execFile . and it worked like charm, but parent file kept waiting for child process. Child process never returns END signal. and this is my code.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

const child = exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" output.mp4', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('stderr: =============================', stderr);
        throw error;
    }
    console.log('stdout: ==========================', stdout);
});

console.log('here');
```

Comment: can someone mention user https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan 

he usually helps everyone with queries related to ffmpeg.

Comment: Did you notice that the error message refers to the filter as `"overlay`? The value option to filter_complex doesn't require quotes unless it has a space. Try w/o quotes, e.g. `[..., '-filter_complex', 'overlay=10:10', ...]` or simply `[..., '-filter_complex overlay=10:10', ...]`

Comment: @marekful , if I type in the command shown like 

>>> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" output.mp4 <<< , it gives me correct output. and you can see that my system says ::: Command failed for : ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" output.mp4 ... why so ?

Comment: It is weird but not unprecedented or something you should spend too much time thinking on. May be a bug in Node but obviously there's a difference in how the terminal and Node's child_process.exec interpret/handle quotes in strings.

Comment: thanks for ur help @marekful

Answer (score 3):

finally found out solution , 
As marekful suggested, the problem was in "overlay=10:10" string ,

so I took another variable str = "overlay=10:10" , and passed that as argument, and it worked like charm.

thanks Marekful.

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const str = "overlay=10:10";
const child = execFile('ffmpeg', ['-i', 'input.mp4' , '-i' , 'logo.png' , '-filter_complex' , str , 'output.mp4' ], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('stderr: =============================', stderr);
        throw error;
    }
    console.log('stdout: ==========================', stdout);
});

console.log('here');
```